# Minesweeper challenge #3

Tags: logical-deduction, probability, minesweeper

I seem to have run into yet another "unsolvable corner" while playing Minesweeper.

The following segment is taken from the bottom right corner of the puzzle. There are 5 mines remaining, and all irrelevant sections have been cropped out.

> [image: Puzzle]

Which squares have the highest probability of being safe? Is there a definite answer to this puzzle? If not, what is the chance I can fully solve it without hitting a mine?

Bonus: Given the below hint, can you guess what the solution was?

> After tapping all the guaranteed safe squares and working from there, I got to a point where there were just two squares remaining with one mine. Unfortunately, I tapped the wrong one, and lost... :( Thankfully, my version of the game has an achievement you can earn for flagging all but one mine on an Expert board, then detonating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following image

> [image] 
>  There is a mine present in each of the three red sections. 
>  Also, there will be two more mines adjacent to the bottom '2'. This makes 5 in total. 
>  Hence, each of the green sections should be free of mines.
>  **Bonus:** If there were a mine in the square below the '3' and a mine in one of the two squares to the right of the '4' (in the red L-shape), then it would be impossible to determine which of these two squares contains the mine. I think this is most likely scenario as there seems to be enough information elsewhere.

Comment: Very good, can you answer the bonus question?

Comment: @gparyani There is at least one situation I can see where the answer would be undetermined. I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Great, on the right track; is it possible to state where the other three mines are, or is that not possible without knowing further information?

Comment: I don't think so. I think there are several situations which could lead to your endpoint.

Comment: I'll keep this question open to more answers, then move to accept.